# How to parallelize nested loops in java 7 (android)

Tags: java, android, parallel-processing

I have the following code snippet

```
 String result;
        for (int s1 = 0; s1 < 10; s1++)
            for (int s2 = 0; s2 < 100; s2++)
                for (int s3 = 0; s3 < 10; s3++)
                    for (int s4 = 0; s4 < 100; s4++)
                    {
                        result = doSomething(s1, s2, s3, s4);
                        if (result != null)
                            addResult(result); //adds results to an ArrayList of strings
                    }
```

How can I parallelize this code to make it faster? I've seen similar posts here parallelizing a single loops but I want to evenly parallelize this whole thing to make it run decently on an android device.

Comment: 3 nested inner loops?? Code-stench for sure

Comment: I doubt there is a much faster way to do it. You are simply iterating a million times. I don't see anything that can be done while "waiting" for a nested loop to finish.

Perhaps you could write two loops with the first one `s1 = 0; s1 < 5` and second one `s1 = 5; s1 < 10`, and run them simultaneously, but it seems unnecessarily complex. I have no idea, though. Just playing with thoughts. Perhaps I should not even have written this comment at all.

Comment: It depends on what doSomething and addResult do.  If doSomething doesn't ever require results of previous loops you can launch N threads and have each of them do a subset of the outermost loop.  (I'm assuming addResult does something like add to a list, where you can merge the lists at the final step).

Comment: You're attempting something called Data Parallel. There is the overhead of separating the work into threads and joining the results which makes it only worthwhile when the Data is huge and the number of threads is large (~16) For the small amount of work you are doing, it simply is not worth the effort.

Comment: I'd say it depends on what do something does. CPU intensive operations like encryption would be a good candidate for parallelization.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `AsyncTask` to parallelize each of the `s1` executions, e.g.:

```
for (int s1 = 0; s1 < 10; s1++)
{
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Object, ArrayList<String>>()
    {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Integer... params)
        {
            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int s2 = 0; s2 < 100; s2++)
            {
                for (int s3 = 0; s3 < 10; s3++)
                {
                    for (int s4 = 0; s4 < 100; s4++)
                    {
                        results.add(doSomething(params[0], s2, s3, s4));
                    }
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results)
        {
            for(String result : results) {
                if (result != null)
                    addResult(result);
            }
        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, s1);
};
```

Note that this assumes that the order of `addResult` calls do not matter, and of course that `doSomething` calls do not interfere with each other by modifying some shared state.

If the order of `addResult` calls do matter, you could solve this by creating an array of all the results, waiting until they all finish (by creating a counter, and waiting until all 10 tasks complete, and then processing the array of results afterwards, in order.

Comment: The amount of threads created here are too much for an android device. This will actually result in slower performance I believe but at least it's a solution I will have to try. Btw the above asynctasks will not be executed in parallel unless you specify `executeOnExecutor`

Comment: Emphasizing ThanosF's point, the AsyncTask docs say, "Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution." The part they don't say is that AsyncTask threads are set at a lower priority, so using it for performance-critical code is not recommended. There are much better approaches in the java.util.concurrent classes.

Comment: Good to know about `executeOnExecutor` and the changes to `AsyncTask`, answer has been updated. 
The answer is meant as a starting point of how to take advantage of `AsyncTask` rather than an optimal solution, as depending on what `doSomething` is doing, 10 might be too many tasks, or too few (e.g. if each `doSomething` were a network request), but this can be easily changed by breaking the loop into sections. Indeed, if this is something that needs to happen often, or something where the overhead of creating a task is relevant, then creating multiple long-lived threads might be more suitable.

Comment: Also realized the loop in the example was returning on the first execution. Fixed it by returning all the results in a list. If the order of `addResult` calls is not important, and they don't need to be performed on the main thread, then the ArrayList and onPostExecute can be entirely removed, as long as `addResult` doesn't have concurrency issues (e.g. is either using thread-safe data structures, or the data structures are `synchronized`).